# Name of the Engineer planet in Alien Covenant

Tags: alien-covenant

Does anyone know the name of the planet (the Engineer Homeworld?) where the crew intercepts the radio signal when on their way to Origae-6?

I think I read somewhere that it is called Paradise, but I can't find anything official.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### There is no name for it.

[image]

Aside from a code-name, which identifies its sector and region, it has no name. From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien:_Covenant):

> As the crew repairs the damage to the ship, they pick up a radio transmission from a nearby unknown planet.

What you may be thinking about is the movie's description:

> Bound for a remote planet on the far side of the galaxy, the crew of the colony ship Covenant discovers what they think is an uncharted **paradise**, but is actually a dark, dangerous world.

---

Edit: From [SynthNorbert](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/51641/synthnorbert)'s answer, I've actually checked the [soundtrack](https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/planet-4-main-theme/id1232494808?i=1232494994&app=itunes) and it mentions the planet as being **Planet 4**. How accurate this information might be, or whether this is just a generic description (like, it's the 4th planet from the sun in that Solar System), I cannot tell. But it is yet another denomination for the Engineer's home planet.

Comment: What was the code-name? Just curious. @BlueMoon93

Comment: You can barely see it in the image, below *Unknown Planet*. 9722-3298 or something similar. I don't have an HD version of the image, so I can't be sure

Answer (score 1):

I remember before it zoomed in on the Engineer planet, you saw a few others planets nearby. And they were labeled as, what looked like a "C" followed by a 3 digit #, much like LV426 (Alien) and LV223 (Prometheus).

I'm assuming they're how the human race sort where planets are, in correlation to Earth.

Comment: Do you have any source? A screenshot maybe?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing further I can particular add to what's already been said other than to say that the planet is referred to as 'Planet 4' this is apparent from both the soundtrack that has a track listed under the name 'Planet 4' but also when Ricks gives his designation of the planets coordinates to the rest of the crew after they intercept the radio signal he refers to the planet as being located in Sector 87 noting it has 2 moons before saying:

'Planet number four is square in the habitable zone. Prime candidate in fact. Zero point nine six G's at the surface. Oceans. Landmass. High likelihood of living biosphere. It's beyond your most optimistic projections for Origae-6.'

You can find further information here: http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Planet_4

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to the accepted answer:

I've added a screen grab or two:

[image]

and got the info from those:

```
main sequence star
sequence C234
stellar azimuth 47.6

unknown: planet
result: 9712-3298
habitable
mass (kg): 7.22 x 10 24
diameter (km): 2350
mean density (kg/m3): 5520

planetary profile>>

surface g-force: 0.96
surface temperature: 28.3 degrees
o2 level: 19 %
nitrogen level: 82 %
argon: 0.93 %
moons: 02

rotation speed: 1023mph
axis angle: 35
```

Note: it says 'unknown: planet' rather than 'unknown planet'. So it looks more like the system that allots classification does not know its name (presumably because there is not one in the database) but decides from the data that it is a planet. Also, before they zoom in on the planet you can see the ships nav computers have already attached reference names to the planets in the system, as seen below.

Also note that while most data is similar to Earth for obvious reasons (albeit hotter), the diameter makes it the size of Pluto, a dwarf planet...

but as you can see, the planet, 4th of the 5 planets, has a reference name attached to it:

```
16EG14
XEN 4309 TN 47.5
```

The other planets are allocated 16EG10-16EG15 (16EG13 is not seen on screen)

The nav display also has a little system orbit map infographic showing the planets orbits in a simplistic manner (as opposed to the main display) and when the actor touches the screen to zoom in, the display lists it as "04".

*However, along with the gibberish (Earth-centered) dialogue about its location, there are always likely to be lots of inaccuracies or things that do not add up in the course of making movies..*

Answer (score -3):

If you look at the soundtrack, you'll see the planets classification is Planet 4.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Perhaps you can add a link or image to the soundtrack to help enhance your answer?